# Delay in dispatching action in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

calling dispatch, and immediately console logging the data. It is showing old data instead of the updated data, unless you add some delay in.

Example based on the redux todo example.

ACTION

```
let nextTodoId = 0
export const addTodo = text => {
  console.log('action');
  return ({
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  })
}
```

REDUCER

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      console.log('reducer');
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.id,
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default todos
```

COMPONENT

```
class AddTodo extends Component {

  render() {
    var _this = this;

    return (
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            this.props.dispatch(addTodo('input.value'))
            console.log('Not updated', this.props.todos);
            setTimeout(function() {
              console.log('Updated', _this.props.todos);
            });
          }}
        >
          <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Output

```
index.js:3 action
todos.js:4 reducer
AddTodo.js:16 Not updated []
AddTodo.js:18 Updated [{…}]
```

AddTodo.js:18 Updated [{…}]

Comment: Updated value will be available in the next render.

Comment: Whenever your "todos" store gets updated, the components using that info should *react* to that change. Where are you using the todos list?

Answer (score 0):

When you dispatch an action, store state is updated by the reducer, and then your mapStateToProps function returns the updated state from the store 
this is the expected behavior, instead of logging it in onSubmit log it in your render

```
render() {
 console.log(this.props.todos)
 .... // remaining code
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Dispaching an action is asynchronous. You will need to use mapStateToProps to get the state from the store in your component. You may use componentWillReceiveProps to get the updated store data.